# Looping doesn't iterate last item in the array

Tags: jquery, arrays

> First loop displays three items which is correct. Second loop affects
>   only two items out of three. Always the second loop affects one item
>   lesser than the first loop. How do to force the second loop to affect
>   all three items or total items?

First loop

```
for (i = 0; i <= 2;i++ ) {
   //calling second looping
console.log("count= "+i);
callMe();
}

 --------------------------------------------------------

var k = 0;
    function callMe()
    {
      k++;
      var data = 0;
      for(;data <= k;data++)
        {
           console.log("data= "+data);
           /*do something here*/
        }
    }
```

Logs:

```
count 0 //first loop
data = 0 //sec loop
data = 1 // sec loop


count 1 //first loop
data = 0 //sec loop
data = 1 //sec loop
data = 2 //sec loop
```

Comment: what is `for(;data <= k;data++)` is something wrong here?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi: it is valid to leave out one or more of the parts of a `for`. The value of `k` is 0 set outside the function, which is wrong.

Comment: Where is `k` set? That value is global, but is being used inside your `callMe` function. That will mess up the counting.

Comment: @Styl: it is global, so must be changed elsewhere, or the results shown are impossible.

Comment: Agreed, I've thrown it into a codepen  and am not getting a match for the output here. Has something been left out?

Comment: callme function will always log `0`. logs presented are seems to be fake.

Comment: `callme` won't log anything, `0 <= 0` <- that second loop never runs

Comment: That's because of the placement of the global definition. The outer (first) loop is evaluated before k is defined. Therefore the exit condition is "0 <= undefined", which returns false. The inner loop exits without a single iteration.

Comment: @GodlyBee Please reply so others are not answering with just assumptions. Do not go away after questioning.

Comment: Also, `i=0; i<2` should only run twice, for `0` and `1`, not three times ?

Comment: @Mic - that's also true, `k` is never hoisted above the `for` loop

Comment: @ParthTrivedi, no notification seen ...by luck just refreshed and saw the comments...Not going away!

Comment: @Mic, thats right, k++ added inside callMe that how its incremented. Sorry I left this out. Just updated

Comment: @adeneo, its i=0; i<=2

Comment: @GodlyBee That k++ won't initialize it, undefined++ returns NaN. Either move the "var k = 0;" to the top of the whole thing, or if callMe is the only place it's used then just put it inside the function.

Comment: @GodlyBee What are you actually trying to get? First loop iterates 0 to 2, and for each iteration the second loop iterates 0 to whichever iteration the first loop is on?

Comment: @Mic, if first loops iterates 0 to 2, second loop iterates 0 to 1.

Comment: @GodlyBee I understand that's what you're seeing, but what do you want it to do?

Comment: @Mic, please refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34635420/last-item-in-the-array-not-afftected  this is what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might work.. as i have doubt abt variable k

```
var k = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 2;i++ ) {
   //calling second looping
console.log("count= "+i);
k++;
callMe(k);

}

 --------------------------------------------------------


function callMe(var j)
{
  var data = 0;
  for(;data <= j;data++)
    {
       console.log("data= "+data);
       /*do something here*/
    }
}
```

Comment: ,still the callMe doesn't affect the last item

Comment: see the change..k++ should be above calling function callMe